# Operations on 'N' dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I am attempting to generalize some Python code to operate on arrays of arbitrary dimension.  The operations are applied to each vector in the array.  So for a 1D array, there is simply one operation, for a 2-D array it would be both row and column-wise (linearly, so order does not matter).  For example, a 1D array (a) is simple:

```
b = operation(a)
```

where 'operation' is expecting a 1D array.  For a 2D array, the operation might proceed as

```
for ii in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    b[ii,:] = operation(a[ii,:])
for jj in range(0,b.shape[1]):
    c[:,ii] = operation(b[:,ii])
```

I would like to make this general where I do not need to know the dimension of the array beforehand, and not have a large set of if/elif statements for each possible dimension.
Solutions that are general for 1 or 2 dimensions are ok, though a completely general solution would be preferred.  In reality, I do not imagine needing this for any dimension higher than 2, but if I can see a general example I will learn something!

Extra information:
I have a matlab code that uses cells to do something similar, but I do not fully understand how it works.  In this example, each vector is rearranged (basically the same function as fftshift in numpy.fft).  Not sure if this helps, but it operates on an array of arbitrary dimension.

```
function aout=foldfft(ain)
nd = ndims(ain);
for k = 1:nd
    nx = size(ain,k);
    kx = floor(nx/2);
    idx{k} = [kx:nx 1:kx-1];
end
aout = ain(idx{:});
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what `operation` could be? Is it some kind of complex function or an arithmetic operation?

Comment: I'd have to run the pieces of the MATLAB to be sure, but I think it is constructing a cell array of size `nd`, with an index range/slice for each dimension. `numpy` functions like `apply_along/over_axis` do something similar, except they have to create a `tuple`.

Comment: @Ophion it is simply a function that takes a single vector (1D array) as an input.  So it's more of a complex function rather than a simple arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Octave, your MATLAB code does:

```
octave:19> size(ain)
ans =
   2   3   4
octave:20> idx
idx = 
{
  [1,1] =
     1   2
  [1,2] =
     1   2   3
  [1,3] =
     2   3   4   1
}
```

and then it uses the `idx` cell array to index `ain`.  With these dimensions it 'rolls' the size 4 dimension.

For 5 and 6 the index lists would be:

```
 2   3   4   5   1
 3   4   5   6   1   2
```

The equivalent in `numpy` is:

```
In [161]: ain=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
In [162]: idx=np.ix_([0,1],[0,1,2],[1,2,3,0])
In [163]: idx
Out[163]: 
(array([[[0]],

        [[1]]]), array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]), array([[[1, 2, 3, 0]]]))
In [164]: ain[idx]
Out[164]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  0],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  4],
        [ 9, 10, 11,  8]],

       [[13, 14, 15, 12],
        [17, 18, 19, 16],
        [21, 22, 23, 20]]])
```

Besides the 0 based indexing, I used `np.ix_` to reshape the indexes.  MATLAB and `numpy` use different syntax to index blocks of values.

The next step is to construct `[0,1],[0,1,2],[1,2,3,0]` with code, a straight forward translation.

I can use `np.r_` as a short cut for turning 2 slices into an index array:

```
In [201]: idx=[]
In [202]: for nx in ain.shape:
    kx = int(np.floor(nx/2.))
    kx = kx-1;
    idx.append(np.r_[kx:nx, 0:kx])
   .....:     
In [203]: idx
Out[203]: [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3, 0])]
```

and pass this through `np.ix_` to make the appropriate index tuple:

```
In [204]: ain[np.ix_(*idx)]
Out[204]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  0],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  4],
        [ 9, 10, 11,  8]],

       [[13, 14, 15, 12],
        [17, 18, 19, 16],
        [21, 22, 23, 20]]])
```

In this case, where 2 dimensions don't roll anything, `slice(None)` could replace those:

```
In [210]: idx=(slice(None),slice(None),[1,2,3,0])
In [211]: ain[idx]
```

======================

`np.roll` does:

```
indexes = concatenate((arange(n - shift, n), arange(n - shift)))
res = a.take(indexes, axis)
```

`np.apply_along_axis` is another function that constructs an index array (and turns it into a tuple for indexing).

Comment: Apply along axis is precisely the function I am looking for.  I can simply iterate over ndim and use b = np.apply_along_axis(operation,a,ii).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a programmatic way to index the `k-th` dimension an `n`-dimensional array, then [`numpy.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) might help you.

An implementation of `foldfft` is given below as an  example:

```
In[1]:
import numpy as np

def foldfft(ain):
    result = ain
    nd = len(ain.shape)
    for k in range(nd):
        nx = ain.shape[k]
        kx = (nx+1)//2
        shifted_index = list(range(kx,nx)) + list(range(kx))
        result = np.take(result, shifted_index, k)
    return result

a = np.indices([3,3])
print("Shape of a = ", a.shape)
print("\nStarting array:\n\n", a)
print("\nFolded array:\n\n", foldfft(a))
```

```
Out[1]:
Shape of a =  (2, 3, 3)

Starting array:

 [[[0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]]]

Folded array:

 [[[2 0 1]
  [2 0 1]
  [2 0 1]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy.ndarray.flat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat), which allows you to linearly iterate over a n dimensional numpy array. Your code should then look something like this:

```
b = np.asarray(x)
for i in range(len(x.flat)):
    b.flat[i] = operation(x.flat[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The folks above provided multiple appropriate solutions.  For completeness, here is my final solution.  In this toy example for the case of 3 dimensions, the function 'ops' replaces the first and last element of a vector with 1.

```
import numpy as np

def ops(s):
    s[0]=1
    s[-1]=1
    return s

a = np.random.rand(4,4,3)
print '------'
print 'Array a'
print a
print '------'
for ii in np.arange(a.ndim):
    a = np.apply_along_axis(ops,ii,a)
    print '------'
    print ' Axis',str(ii)
    print a
    print '------'
    print ' '
```

The resulting 3D array has a 1 in every element on the 'border' with the numbers in the middle of the array unchanged.  This is of course a toy example; however ops could be any arbitrary function that operates on a 1D vector.

Flattening the vector will also work; I chose not to pursue that simply because the book-keeping is more difficult and apply_along_axis is the simplest approach.

[apply_along_axis reference page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)